# Getting error in debug : price was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I am getting below error in debug mode. Please can any one help me with this, I am working on this from lart two day, but  no luck.

> Notice: price was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be
>   accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'),
>   require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('wp_loaded'),
>   WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action,
>   WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_variable, WC_Cart->add_to_cart,
>   do_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   WC_Cart->calculate_totals,
>   do_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   GWP_Custom_Product_Tabs->add_custom_price,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 3.0.) in
>   /home/example-com/public/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 4196

Comment: Which code is causing this notice?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually I am not getting from where this error is coming.

Comment: The problem is in whatever "GWP_Custom_Product_Tabs" is. Does that sound like something you've developed or installed?

Comment: Hi Jacob, Thanks. Yes I found a custom code done in website by someone with GWP_Custom_Product_Tabs class... I am checking this now..